# Program a handler for a stop loss

Tags: mql5

I would like to execute a series of commands every time when a stop loss (or take profit) automatically triggers.

I am not sure how to do it, because I haven't found handlers for these events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void OnTradeTransaction(const MqlTradeTransaction& trans,const MqlTradeRequest& request,const MqlTradeResult& result)
   {
    if(trans.type!=TRADE_TRANSACTION_DEAL_ADD)return;
    if(!HistoryDealSelect(trans.deal))return;
    if(HistoryDealGetInteger(trans.deal,DEAL_MAGIC)!=InpMagicNumber)return;
    if(HistoryDealGetInteger(trans.deal,DEAL_ENTRY)!=DEAL_ENTRY_OUT)return;
    if(HistoryDealGetString(trans.deal,DEAL_SYMBOL)!=_Symbol)return;
    long reason=HistoryDealGetInteger(trans.deal,DEAL_REASON);
    if(reason==DEAL_REASON_SL)
       {
        Print(__LINE__,__FILE__," we are afraid SL is hit);
       }
    else if(reason==DEAL_REASON_TP)
       {
        Print(__LINE__,__FILE__," TP is HIT!);
       }
   }
```

Comment: just in case it was MQL4/5 question, MQL4 does not support this magic. `OnTradeTransaction()` is basic event so no need to put it anywhere, it is another event handler like `OnTick` or `OnTimer`

Comment: Could you edit your answer with a small explanation? Because "HistoryDealGetInteger(trans.deal,DEAL_REASON);"  always returns 0.

Comment: `https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/constants/tradingconstants/dealproperties#enum_deal_reason` is list of reasons. if you close a deal manually reason is 0. try to wait till sl or tp is hit. You can also convert your reason into `string` using `EnumToString`

Comment: You would first need to cast `reason` from `long` to `ENUM_DEAL_REASON` before using `EnumToString`

Comment: Ok! One more question, is it possible that the handler is executed in the next tick? After debugging, is what I see...

Comment: `OnTradeTransaction` is called independently of `OnTick`. Of course in tester it works one after another, depending on the delay you have set, in real time it is unknown which of the two events comes first.